# Why is <form> being given NoValidate attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, jquery-validate

Having trouble getting jQuery Validate plugin to play nice.

Model

```
public class FooVM
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/content/bootstrap-responsive.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/content/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="navbar">
                    <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <a class="brand" href="#">idoneit</a>
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="menu-link">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "index", "bar")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span12 error-container">

            </div>
            <div class="span12 main-body">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

View

```
model bootstrapvalidate.Models.FooVM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("add", "bar", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <legend>Testing Bootstrap & Validate</legend>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label for="Name" class="control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
              @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) 
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Add!</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

When I submit, the error message is briefly shown and then the form posts back anyway.

One thing I have noticed which I have not seen before is that the markup contains the 'novalidate' attribute

```
<form action="/bar/add" class="form-horizontal" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

From the bits I have read, this is HTML5 attribute that prevents validation. So yeah, this is what is causing it I assume.

Question is - why the bejesus is it being added to the form? I've not asked for it!

edit: did a bit of digging based on @rob 's answer, it seems jquery validate is throwing an exception, hence the postback..

[image: Debugging Outcome]

this is jquery.validate 1.10

Comment: As per the [plugin's page](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), version 1.10 has only been tested up through jQuery 1.8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was really a poorly worded question on my part I think.

Essentially the issue was not the `novalidation` attribute at all (as @robasta said).

I couldn't get jQuery 1.9 and jQuery.Validate 1.10 to play nicely. Switching back to jQuery 1.83 fixed it straight away, all working as I'd expect.

Comment: Version 1.10 has only been tested up through jQuery 1.8.x

Comment: Will teach me to be more thorough before playing about, I only really wanted to try out Boostrap :)

Comment: you'd better report a bug, it helped me (and i hope many others) with one photo gallery

Comment: i wonder if jquery 1.10 + the jquery migration plugin is supported? i'm about to find out...

Comment: I've just experienced this issue with jQuery.validate v1.14 so looks to still be an issue.  Solution remains to not upgrade jQuery beyond 1.8.3 (disappointing)

Answer (score 33):

The [`novalidate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) attribute is added by jquery.validate line 32:

```
// Add novalidate tag if HTML5.
this.attr('novalidate', 'novalidate');
```

If you are using HTML5, [then remove the attribute](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/disable-jquery-validate-when-html5-form-validation-is-present):

```
$("#contactForm").validate();
$("#contactForm").removeAttr("novalidate");
```

In your `web.config`, make sure you have:

```
 <appSettings>        
    ...
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

Also make sure they are not commented out.

Comment: Good shout - but they are both there, and not commented out

Comment: To clarify, my understanding is the `novalidate` is supposed to be there to turn off HTML5 validation, because you don't want both HTML5 validation(implemented in the browser) and jQuery validation to both be trying to validate the form, as they will produce duplicate error popups that will be messy.

Comment: Aaron's comment is the true answer to "why" novalidate is added.  It's a bit deceptive because it sounds like you're disabling validation, but you're just disabling it in the browser which allows jquery to pick it up to handle it instead.  This allows for a more consistent experience across browsers (since each browser may handle it slightly different) and JQuery's (err your) implementation is likely to be done a lot better (e.g showing all validation issues instead of doing one at a time)

Answer (score 6):

From a quick scan and reading through previous comments, I am noticing that if you have the `data-val=true` attribute on any of the items in the form, the novalidate property will automatically be inserted by `jquery.validate`.

This makes sense because if you are using those attributes then there is something that you do not intend to go through validation, hence the novalidate attribute; however, by reading up on the html5 `novalidate` property on w3schools, you can overwrite the default `novalidate`; the new `jquery.validate` script must account for this.

I think that's the skinny, let me know if anyone agrees.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
// Add novalidate tag if HTML5.
this.attr('novalidate', 'novalidate');
```

to

```
// Add novalidate tag if HTML5.
    if (typeof (Worker) !== "undefined") { this.attr('novalidate', 'novalidate');
```

Answer (score -2):

for default jquery form validations
add this attribute in Html.BeginForm
@novalidate=""