# novalidate attribute being added to form

Tags: c#, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am working on an application and I noticed that my form validation was not working, after some investigation and fixes, it seemingly began to work but with a flaw, validation was only being added to the single tab being viewed at the moment.
If I submit the form while being on another tab the validation would not fire and it will carry me to an error page.

Upon more investigation I noticed my page having a 'novalidate' attirbute and for the life of me I cannot figure out why it's there, nor how to remove it even after reading this similar question.

[Why is <form> being given NoValidate attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438325/why-is-form-being-given-novalidate-attribute)

**How I have tried to solve this**

As instructed by  this question I have tried to remove the attribute on my form and I have made sure the code shown is available in the `web.config`.

I also read that it may be an error somewhere in my model so I commented out the entire model so there was no "Required" fields, basically I did  various tinkering around and nothing stand out to me as a reason why NoValidate will attach itself to my form.
I have also tried a script to turn on validation for all forms not just the visible ones and, no change.
I have placed some of my code below, please inform me if there's something I may have missed why novalidate is there or as to why my page will only validate on the visible tab.

Code Below

BundlesConfig

```
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Content/Gridmvc.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/Gridmvc.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

Model 
 **MetaData.cs Class**

```
[MetadataType(typeof(metaStudent))]
    public partial class Studentinfo
    {

        public class metaStudent
        {

         DisplayName("Image")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase image { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
            [DisplayName("First Name")]
            public string firstname { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Middle Name")]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Middle Name is required")]
            public string middlename { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
            [DisplayName("Last Name")]
            public string lastname { get; set; }

            [DisplayName("Village")]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Village is required")]
 public Nullable<int> village { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include="studentid,firstname,middlename,lastname,villag")] Studentinfo studentinfo, HttpPostedFileBase stuimage)
        {
            try
            {


                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
```

View

```
@model Edu_StuConsole_App.Models.STU_studentinfo

@{

    ViewBag.Title = "Student";
}
@section scripts {
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
@*<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>*@
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    }


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
            todayBtn: "linked",
            autoclose: true,
            maxDate: "+0D",
            todayHighlight: true,
            orientation: 'top auto',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-100:+0"
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#myform').validate({
            ignore: [],
            // any other options and/or rules
        });

    });
    $("#frm").validate();
    $("#frm").removeAttr("novalidate");
</script>


<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <h3 class="title-hero">
            Add Student
        </h3>
        <div class="example-box-wrapper">
            <ul class="nav-responsive nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Personal Information</a></li>


                <li>
                    <a href="#tab_1_2" data-toggle="tab"> Contact Information </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#tab_1_3" data-toggle="tab"> Income Information </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
            <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Student", null, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frm", enctype = "multipart/form-data", @data_ajax = "false" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div

 class="form-horizontal">
                        <h4></h4>

                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.image, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input type="file" name="stuimage" id="stuimage" accept="image/*" style=" width: 100%;" onchange="check()" />

                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.image, new { type = "file" }) 
                                         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.image)
                                                  </div>
                                </div>



<div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.studentid, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.studentid, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.studentid)
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firstname, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.firstname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.firstname)
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.middlename, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.middlename, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.middlename)
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lastname, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lastname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lastname)
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

**Small Potion of Layout page**

```
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'><![endif]-->
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")


...
   </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"for the life of me I cannot figure out why it's there"* ~ Really?  The link you provided clearly explains why... that the jQuery Validate plugin adds this attribute dynamically.  This is designed to disable all HTML5 validation while using the jQuery Validate plugin.  If you want to use jQuery Validate, then you would/should **never** want/need to remove the `novalidate` attribute. See this for more:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549260/why-is-jquery-validation-adding-novalidate-attribute

Comment: @Sparky But I am not using jQuery, Im trying to use my model as always.

Comment: What are you talking about?!  You've included jQuery and jQuery Validate code within your OP, as well as you tagged the question with jQuery and jQuery Validate!

Comment: I think you're confused about the purpose of the `novalidate` attribute.  It's sole purpose is to disable the client-side HTML5 browser validation, which you don't need because you're using jQuery Validate on the client-side.

Comment: @Sparky yes, I see where I included it, however, it was in an attempt to get my browser validation to work.

Comment: You are really confused!  If you want browser validation, then you don't want jQuery Validation.  One **or** the other.